# Populate values from Java Restful Service into JSP Page

Tags: jsp, java

I created a Java Restful Service using JSON and I am getting some value from this service then I want to populate these value on one JSP page.

My "test.jsp" page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtFirstname" value='<%=request.getParameter("firstinput")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" value='<%=request.getParameter("firstinput")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My service.java code is below

```
package test.xyz.abc;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/")
public class Service {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat returnDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Path("/auth")
    public void Auth(String json) {
        Date dt = new Date();
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        String currentTime = formatter.format(dt);
        JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject innerJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            String email = innerJsonObj.getString("email");
            String fname = innerJsonObj.getString("fname");

            //How to put email and fname values into "test.jsp" page
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

"web.xml" code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>test</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using Eclipse Mars1 and Java.

Comment: You'd need to call the service while rendering your JSP to get the values in there. This alone should make you wonder whether this is a feasible approach. You might be better off using JavaScript (maybe a framework based on JS) or using a different service (could be something that the RESTful service and the JSP both call.

Comment: You want ot use the webservice during the generation of the JSP ? Then why use a webservice if you are calling it from the server ? Call the method directly (not pretty) or move the logic into an controler class and redirect the service into it. Return an instance to work in JSTL in the JSP

Comment: @AxelH I have to create one Service that is used for post JSON data and I have to get this data and show on my JSP page.

Comment: Into the JSP or into the page receive by the client (in HTML) ?

Comment: @AxelH Yes. into the page receive by the client (.JSP)

Comment: @AxelH Client is POST JSON into my Java Service and then I have to get these details or data and show into .JSP page, this page is recieved by client.

Comment: Ok, my mistake because the client doens't receive a JSP page, it has the JSP extension but this is pure HTML so I misunderstand. Well, Thomas point you on the right way. I would use the Ajax (see pure Javascript Ajax or with JQuery) to call the Webservice and read the result. Here, a random page of SO about Ajax with JQuery : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211981/jquery-ajax-parse-json-response

Comment: @AxelH I did not understand what i have to do? Should i have to change my "service.java" code or create one jsp page where i write code for post JSON?

Comment: Look at my edit. You will found what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking about a JSP page, meaning that you are still on the server. So you don't need to use the webservice (a door to access the server).

Create a controler that will create an instance (with email and name). You can call this method into the servlet to push it as attribute in the JSP.

```
interface Controler {
    public Auth auth(); return an instance of Auth(String email, String fname)
}
```

In the Servlet class, get the result an push it directly (need to be a BEAN).

```
class Servlet { 
    Controler c; //Create a instance of the implementation of Controler 

    doGet(...) { //push attribute of c.auth() }
}
```

Then you just need to update the JSP to work with the attribute you send to populate the page.

Later, if you want some AJAX, use the WebService to call the controler method. Convert the instance into a JSON to send the result.

```
class Service{
    Controler c; //Create a instance of the implementation of Controler 

    //NEED TO RETURN A STRING
    public String Auth(){
        return c.auth()
                          .toJson() //Return a JSON with the data of the instance
                          .toString(); //parsing the JSON in a String
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Since you only want ot get this value dynamicly from the client. You are going to need to use Javascript to call in Ajax your webservice. This will retreive the JSON you create. Of course, you need to correct your service to return something, your auth doesnt return anything.

SO parse the JSON you create into String (toString() work).

And from the Javascript part, you will need to create the JSON from the String, luckily, this is also really simple. Using JQuery, you just need to specifiy that you await a json, the data will be an javascrip object. If not, you need to parse the String yourself, look at the following to see how to get some data from a url (in JSON) :

[Jquery/Ajax - Parse JSON Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211981/jquery-ajax-parse-json-response)

With this, you can do it.